# For Each Loop Unable to assign value to a variable

Tags: foreach, ssis, msbi

I have an Execute SQL Tasks which gets the Missing Ids and stores them into an ObjectVariable(MissingIDs of DataType Object).Using the For Each Loop Container I wanna Insert data into a multi tenant architecture DB based on that ID's Name(which will be the name of the schema). I've Used For Each ADO Enumerator and Used the ObjectVariable(MissingIDs) as ADO ObjectSourcevariable and enumeration mode as "Rows in First Table".In Variable mappings I mapped it to another variable(CompanyID) of dataType String with Index as 0.

In For Each Container,I wish to get the name of the ID and store in a variable called schema(DataType String).I've used Execute SQL Task to do this but I am getting an error.

Error: 0xC002F309 at Getting Schema Name for the AccountID, Execute SQL Task: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "schema": "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned.".
Task failed: Getting Schema Name for the AccountID

I've used Breakpoints and am able to see that the data is available AccountID.

Anyone knows where the issue could be?

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Sounds like the execute SQL task to populate `Schema` is returning NULL for some CompanyIDs.   Is this expected behavior, or do you have a problem in your SQL?

Comment: execute SQL task is not returing any NULL values. I verified this step and found that Execute SQl task is working fine but the next step which is For each loop container is failing.

Comment: What is the query you have used for Execute sql task? Is it returning only 1 column? What is the point of using Schema variable when you can directly use CompanyId variable?

Comment: Execute SQLTASK has Select AccountID from Table where TARGET_REF_ID is NULL...This lists all the CompanyIDs that are not available in the Target DB.I store them to MissingIDs variable of DataType Object. FOr Each AccountID i need to create a new schema based on tyhe name of the AccountID and around 40 tables related to that schema.Hence in the for Loop based on MissingIDs variable, I mapped it to CompanyID Variable..In the For Loop I run a SP to create Schema and tables based on the parameter 'Schema' and Hence I need to assign a value to schema from the related name column for each AccountID.

Comment: If the table you're selecting from initially (to get the list of missing IDs) already has the name, you should just select both the ID and name columns into your object variable, and then set up two variable mappings in the "for each" task - one to hold the ID, and one to hold the name. Then you won't need the later execute SQL task that's not working. If you're still having trouble, I'd suggest maybe linking to some screenshots if possible - it might be easier to spot the issue that way. Edit your original post to include all the extra information you've given.